# Short disturbance during calls with my Galaxy S3 LTE SHV E210s

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

I have a Samsung Galaxy S3 4g/LTE phone. When I call any one or when I receive a call, there is a disturbing noise, like scratching a dvd movie disc. 
What caused the problem and how do I solve this?

Comment: "After call received" -- can you detail this? Do you mean when hanging up the call or when call was picked up by other party or after hanging up the call? Have you confirmed whether others users over the web has or had the similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

Update you phone to 4.4.4 kitkat version from wifi and then type on phone keybad *#9090# and press call. This will show the hidden menu of your SHV-E210S.

Got to Network Mode Set -> GSM_Enable. This will turn your phone to work for GSM networks. Return to main screen and restart your phone.